# How to calculate combined false acceptance/rejection rates of multiple biometrics authentication systems?

Tags: biometrics

I am a taking a network security class at grad school, and I need a little help with my assignment question. I am trying to think this through, and just want to know whether my approach is right or wrong.

Question:

> To deal with false acceptance and false rejection, multiple biometrics authentication
>   schemes can be combined to authenticate a user. Consider the combination where the user
>   is authenticated as long as a user passes one of the biometric tests: Retina Scan, Finger
>   print or Voice Recognition. Suppose the false acceptance rates of retina scan, ngerprint and
>   voice recognition are f a1, f a2, and f a3. And their false rejection rates are fr1, fr2, and fr3
>   respectively. Assuming the above false acceptance and false rejection rates are independent,
>   what are the false acceptance rate and the false rejection rate of the above combined scheme?

When I read the question - I immediately thought that the users (legit or not, but specially non-legit since we're talking about *false* acceptance) would start using the one method that would let them in most easily. So the false acceptance rate of the combined scheme would be max(fa1, fa2, fa3). Likewise, I thought legit users would not want to be rejected therefore they would use the one method that has the least amount of rejection, hence I think the combined false rejection rate of the system will be min(fr1, fr2, fr3).

If I am not onto something here, and missing something completely, please direct me to what I should read/study so I get on to the correct path.

Comment: Added homework tag as requested :]

Comment: Also - I just discovered the word 'independent' gives it away how to solve the question. So I have got it, I will post the 'approach' myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rates of each device are independent of each other, and the user is authenticated when any one of the devices authenticates the user, we have the following information:

A user is rejected if and only if all three devices reject him (him is used throughout to represent him or her), therefore, the combined rejection rate becomes:

FR = fr1 * fr2 * fr3

So we know that introducing more biometrics systems lower the overall false rejection rate.

Now, to calculate the rate that any one of these produces a false accept:

```
FA = 1 - Niether 1, nor 2, nor 3 produce fa
   = 1 - [(1 - fa1)(1 - fa2)(1 - fa3)]
   = 1 - [(1 - fa1 - fa2 + fa1fa2)(1 - fa3)]
   = 1 - (1 - fa1 - fa2 + fa1fa2 - fa3 + fa1fa3 + fa2fa3 - fa1fa2fa3)
   = 1 - 1 + fa1 + fa2 + fa3 - fa1fa2 - fa2fa3 - fa3fa1 + fa1fa2fa3
   = fa1 + fa2 + fa3 - fa1fa2 - fa2fa3 - fa3fa1 + fa1fa2fa3
```